# Laravel 5.8 LDAP Authentication not working - LdapRecord Package

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to implements an LDAP authentication in an application for my company. I'm using Laravel 5.8 and the LdapRecord package

I have succeed to connect the application with the LDAP server test see Successfully connected and my  to authenticate with openldap to  online server its also Successfully. but when i want to do the authentication with active directory to my app it not working  , Why who can help me?
Here is my code :

The **.env**

```
LDAP_LOGGING=true
LDAP_CONNECTION=default
LDAP_HOST=server
LDAP_PORT=389
LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=mydomain,dc=local"
LDAP_TIMEOUT=5
LDAP_SSL=false
LDAP_TLS=false
```

The **ldap.php**

```
return [

 

    'default' => env('LDAP_CONNECTION', 'default'),

 

    'connections' => [

        'default' => [
            'hosts' => [env('LDAP_HOST', 'server')],
            'username' => env('LDAP_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('LDAP_PASSWORD', ''),
            'port' => env('LDAP_PORT', 389),
            'base_dn' => env('LDAP_BASE_DN', 'dc=mydomain,dc=local'),
            'timeout' => env('LDAP_TIMEOUT', 5),
            'use_ssl' => env('LDAP_SSL', false),
            'use_tls' => env('LDAP_TLS', false),
        ],

    ],

 

    'logging' => env('LDAP_LOGGING', true),

 

    'cache' => [
        'enabled' => env('LDAP_CACHE', false),
        'driver' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
    ],

];
```

The **auth.php**

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'ldap',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

  

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent' ,
            'model' => App \ User :: class,
        ],
        'ldap' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
          'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,
         //   'model' => LdapRecord\Models\OpenLDAP\User::class,
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\User::class,
                'sync_passwords' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'name' => 'cn',
                    'email' => 'mail',
                ],
            ],
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

 

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

  

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

The **user.php** model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\LdapAuthenticatable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\AuthenticatesWithLdap;

class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, AuthenticatesWithLdap, HasLdapUser ;

    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',

    ];
 
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token' ,
    ];

  
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

The **LoginController**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {

  

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
 
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'uid' => $request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->get('password'),
        ];
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Is there anyone who has already used this package and can help me on my code ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried setting SSL or RLS to true? IIRC AD needs a secure connection...

Comment: thanks for the feedback, this problem has already been resolved

Comment: So @АлинаСмирнова, how did you resolve the issue? Your solution may be useful to others.